# How to scroll images and data of images in uitableviewcell in ios using objective c.?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

### What i done before?

- My **UITableViewCell** contains inside of **cell** **UIScrollView**,images,label,button etc.
- That cell shows user profile images and content of images.

  ### What the actual problem is?
- My **UIScrollView** **scroll** but could **not shown the data** (images and content of images) **on next index,** **my cell** look like:

[image]

### What i done before?

- Here my code that i tried before.

  ```
    -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView   cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
     {
       CustomeTableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
       NSArray *dict1=mainData;
       for (int i =indexPath.row; i < dict1.count; i++)
       {
         CGRect frame;
         frame.origin.x = cell.images.frame.size.width * i;
         frame.origin.y=36;
         frame.size = cell.images.frame.size;
         cell.scrollVIew.pagingEnabled = YES;
         UIImageView *img=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
         img=[cell.scrollVIew.subviews objectAtIndex:0];
         img=cell.images;
         [img sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat :@"%@%@%@",defaulturl,event_gallery_small,
         [[dict1 valueForKey:@"filepath"]objectAtIndex:i]]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"image_default.png"]];
         CGRect frame1;
         frame1.origin.x = cell.eventImg.frame.size.width * i;
         frame1.origin.y=3;
         frame1.size = cell.eventImg.frame.size;
         UIImageView *img1=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame1];
         img1=[cell.scrollVIew.subviews objectAtIndex:0];
         img1=cell.eventImg;
         [cell.eventImg sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat :@"%@%@",thumbs, [[dict1 valueForKey:@"event_pic"] objectAtIndex:i]]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"image_default.png"]];
        cell.eventImg.clipsToBounds=YES;
        cell.eventImg.layer.cornerRadius=
                                  cell.eventImg.frame.size.width/2;
        CGRect frame2;
        frame2.origin.x = cell.eventName.frame.size.width * i;
        frame2.origin.y=8;
        frame2.size = cell.eventName.frame.size;
        UILabel *lbl=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame2];
        lbl=cell.eventName;
        lbl.text=[[dict1 valueForKey:@"ename"] objectAtIndex:0];

        CGRect frame3;
        frame3.origin.x = cell.likeCount.frame.size.width * i;
        frame3.origin.y=267;
        frame3.size = cell.likeCount.frame.size;
        UILabel *lbl1=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame3];
        lbl1=cell.likeCount;
        lbl1.text=[[dict1 valueForKey:@"like_count"] objectAtIndex:i];

        CGRect frame4;
        frame4.origin.x = cell.blastCount.frame.size.width * i;
        frame4.origin.y=267;
        frame4.size = cell.blastCount.frame.size;
        UILabel *lbl2=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame4];
        lbl2=cell.blastCount;
        lbl2.text=[[dict1 valueForKey:@"blast_count"] objectAtIndex:i];

        CGRect frame5;
        frame5.origin.x = cell.commentCount.frame.size.width * i;
        frame5.origin.y=267;
        frame5.size = cell.commentCount.frame.size;
        UILabel *lbl3=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame5];
        lbl3=cell.commentCount;
        lbl3.text=[[dict1 valueForKey:@"comment_count"] objectAtIndex:i];

        CGRect frame6;
        frame6.origin.x = cell.userName.frame.size.width * i;
        frame6.origin.y=290;
        frame6.size = cell.userName.frame.size;
        UILabel *lbl4=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame6];
        lbl4=cell.userName;
        lbl4.text=[[dict1 valueForKey:@"username"] objectAtIndex:i];

        CGRect frame7;
        frame7.origin.x =cell.txtDescrption.frame.size.width * i;
        frame7.origin.y=319;
        frame5.size = cell.txtDescrption.frame.size;
        UITextField *txt=[[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:frame7];
        txt=cell.txtDescrption;
        txt.text=[[dict1 valueForKey:@"description"] objectAtIndex:i];

        [cell.scrollVIew  addSubview:txt];
        [cell.scrollVIew addSubview:lbl];
        [cell.scrollVIew addSubview:lbl1];
        [cell.scrollVIew addSubview:lbl2];
        [cell.scrollVIew addSubview:lbl3];
        [cell.scrollVIew addSubview:lbl4];
        [cell.scrollVIew addSubview:img1];
        [cell.scrollVIew addSubview:img];
        }

        cell.scrollVIew.contentSize =  CGSizeMake(cell.scrollVIew.frame.size.width * dict1.count, cell.scrollVIew.frame.size.height);


       return cell;
       }
  ```

### What i want?

- I want to scroll my data (images and content of images),please see my code and correct me where i am wrong,or refer me an example or code that resolve my issue.Thanks in advance.!

Comment: put nslog & hit url on google check that your image is present there..

Comment: Dear Mukesh i already checked that,its fine but i don't know whay is not showing on next index.You can check that http://soshalife.com/soshalife/services/event_gallery/small/

Comment: Why you are using for loop ? instead you can directly read values from indexPath.row

Comment: Did you meant that i use without loop?Did you please clear me what i should do....Thanks.!

Comment: Before i going to explain could you tell me what this stand for in thw for loop `CGRect frame; frame.origin.x = cell.images.frame.size.width * i;`

Comment: I use without loop but still data not shown on next index what i should that..?

Comment: Simply creating a frame of images "cell.images" is that property that i create on custom class.

Comment: could not understand send your project on mukesh.lokare1@gmail.com

Comment: Please check your mail and after correct that send me on my mail thanks.If you not get mail please tell me i am waiting for your reply.Thanks.!

Comment: You have to do little more work for use `collectionView` in `UITableViewCell` for this.

Comment: How can i do..? i did not use collectionview before did you code me an example of collectionview in my code please or refer me an example.Thanks.!

Comment: Dear Mukesh,i changed lilte bit then its working fine,now its scroll and also shown next index image but now problem is that only images is scrolling the content of images could not shown on next index.I dont know why this is happing..??

Comment: write answer your self, mention what was problem & how you have fixed might be help others in future. good luck